# emacs 24.4.1 image support - can't find libpng16.dll binary

Tags: image, dll, emacs

I am using Windows 8 64bit trying to get image support for emacs.  Here is the result of C-h C-a
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
 of 2014-10-24 on LEG570

here is dynamic-library-alist:

```
((xpm "libxpm.dll" "xpm4.dll" "libXpm-nox4.dll") (png "libpng16.dll" "libpng16-16.dll") (tiff "libtiff-5.dll" "libtiff3.dll" "libtiff.dll") (jpeg "libjpeg-9.dll") (gif "libgif-7.dll") (svg "librsvg-2-2.dll") (gdk-pixbuf "libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll") (glib "libglib-2.0-0.dll") (gobject "libgobject-2.0-0.dll") (gnutls "libgnutls-28.dll" "libgnutls-26.dll") (libxml2 "libxml2-2.dll" "libxml2.dll") (zlib "zlib1.dll" "libz-1.dll"))
```

Here is the contents of emacs24/bin:

```
  c:/Users/charles/emacs24/bin:
  total used in directory 26417 available 425207560
  drwxrwxrwx  1 charles None    4096 01-12 16:58 .
  drwxrwxrwx  1 charles None       0 01-09 22:03 ..
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  590441 01-09 22:01 addpm.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  978880 01-09 22:01 ctags.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  730198 01-09 22:01 ebrowse.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None 9220110 01-09 22:01 emacs-24.4.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None 9220110 01-09 22:01 emacs.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None 1021304 01-09 22:01 emacsclient.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  667492 01-09 22:01 emacsclientw.exe
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  975457 01-09 22:01 etags.exe
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None   31744 01-12 16:58 giflib4.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None    7168 01-09 22:01 grep-changelog
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None  153966 01-12 16:58 jpeg62.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None  532345 01-09 22:01 libXpm.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None 1243248 01-12 16:58 libglib-2.0-0.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None  341425 01-12 16:58 libgobject-2.0-0.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None  230529 01-12 16:58 libpng14-14.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None   77900 01-12 16:58 librle3.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None  375296 01-12 16:58 libtiff3.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None   31232 01-12 16:58 libungif4.dll
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 charles None  494367 01-09 22:01 runemacs.exe
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None   52224 01-12 16:58 xpm4.dll
  -rw-rw-rw-  1 charles None   70656 01-12 16:58 zlib1.dll
```

My problem - I can't seem to find a BINARY for libpng16.dll or libpng16-16.dll. Lots of source code out there but no binaries.  I found libpng15-15.dll in both 32 and 64 bit versions at /www.gtk.org/download/win32.php - not that I know which of the two would work.  I can NOT find libpng15.dll either - I am using a 64 bit windows8 computer but I THINK the emacs precompiled version that I am using is 32 bit....  Can anyone help?

Comment: i just downloaded libpng16-16.dll from ezwinports - copied it into my /bin directory - restarted emacs and still no image support or jpg support.  By the way I have downloaded ghostscript and put it in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: There is a 64 bit emacs trunk available on the net and it includes all the dll files for that particular build.  Perhaps you could try that build, or borrow the dll that you need.  There is also a 32 bit build of Emacs for the latest public release that Vincent Goulet puts out -- you can copy all the dll from that build also, or simply use his build instead of what you are using.  Here is the link to Vincent Goulet's 32-bit build that includes the dll files:  http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/  Here is the 64-bit trunk version:  http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Download libpng-1.6.12-w32-bin.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/, then copy both libpng16.dll and zlib1.dll to emacs24/bin (zlib1.dll is necessary)

Comment: Just wanted to mention that libpng-1.6.12-w32-bin.zip has the file named bin/libpng16-16.dll - I believe that's a typo.  I had to rename the file to libpng16.dll to get emacs to work with that dll.